# Is there an R-package to calculate pseudo R-squared measures for conditional (fixed effects) logistic models using clogit or bife?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

Is there a R-package to calculate pseudo R-squared measures for my model? rcompanion neither supports clogit nor bife (due to missing intercept?).

Originally that was one question out of a larger context, which I edited to make it more readable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi xander23, I think what you have are valid questions, and although they are related to the same dataset, answering all 5 at one go is a tall task. Since there is already an answer for 5, how about editing this question as just that?

Comment: I can give you some comments about 1 to 4, but I encourage you to post them as questions, with a small sample of your dataset. 1. strata is meant for matched group, i.e same patients, before after treatment etc.. Is this the case here?

Comment: 2. if you have so many variables etc, most likely approximate is the way to go, although you need to check whether the coefficients make sense. I cannot tell what is the "approximate" method from reading the manual. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.44-1.1/topics/clogit , you can try also "efron" and compare the coefficients.

Comment: 3. From what I can read, seems like bife is faster, https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-10-12/web/packages/bife/vignettes/bife_introduction.html, I am not familiar with this and you to come up with a method of evaluating your model

Comment: 4. What to do about missing values for lasso?

Comment: Hi StupidWolf, thank for your input. By editing you mean create 5 separate questions? Can I do that without losing the already given answers?

Comment: How about editing this question to be, Is there a R-package to calculate pseudo R-squared measures  for clogit? Then your 4 other questions can be 2 or 3 separate questions. You will not lose the answer below

Comment: Ok. I see. I try that.

Comment: @StupidWolf. I have split the questions, and added more details. Hope it will be more clear now. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59010222/12275275  Unfortunately I don't know how to provide an adequate reprex on that matter.

Comment: Thanks @xander23. Yeah you can include a brief description of the model you are running. And as for R-square.. do you think it's useful? R-square = 1 - SSE/SST. In this case, your outcome is either 0 or 1. Yes you can use pseudo R^2 but isn't better to assess your accuracy? I.e how many predictions you get correct?

Comment: And sorry for the misunderstanding that led to your much reduced post. You have an imbalanced dataset and if the model just predict everything as 0, it will still perform well on accuracy or pseudo R^2. I think you need to consider this..

Comment: @StupidWolf: Shall we move this discussion to the newly asked question? I will gladly elaborate on this.

Comment: @StupidWolf: I will test the model out-of-sample as well. If useful, I would provide pseudo r2 like nagelkerke, mcfadden. But like you and Sal Mangiafico already mentioned, providing those might not be useful in that case. Maybe efron would be more appropriate. r-square is not useful do to the non-linear nature of the model.

Comment: @xander23 Did you ever find a solution? clogit summary gives a R squared but it's not clear to me which one it is. library(performance) calculates Nagelkerkes R squared for clogit objects, but I can't find any explicit documentation so unsure whether the results are reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to question 5:  Definitions for pseudo r-squared values based (mostly) on log likelihood values are given by [UCLA IDRE](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/).  If you are able to extract the log likelihood from the fitted model and null model, calculating these measures is fairly straightforward. I don't know which, if any, of these might make sense for this kind of model. If the log likelihood values are not available for this kind of model are not available, Efron's pseudo r-square, which is based on the predicted and actual *y* values.  This might be serviceable in this case; I don't know.

Comment: @ Sal Mangiafico: Thanks for your answer. Due to the NA values, the null model and fitted model will differ in size. Do I have to adjust the null model to the fitted model (complete.cases) prior to calculating the pseudo - r squared? When using glm I get a warning that rows are different for both models.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that the models should be properly nested.  So they should be based on the same observations.  So, yes, any observation excluded in the fitted model should be excluded in the null model.